# Jquery AJAX error in Mozilla when reading a local XML file

Tags: jquery

I am reading some properties from an XML file. It is working fine on IE but not in mozilla firefox. My application is running locally on user's local machine and I am reading XML from local drive.

In Firefox the AJAX call to open the document does not succeed. Below is my code snippet.

How can I get this to work in Firefox?

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../branding.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        parseXml(xml);
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(xml) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

I receive the following notice in Firebug:

```
"[Exception... \"Access to restricted URI denied\" code: \"1012\" 
nsresult: \"0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)\" 
location: \"file:///M:/index/js/jquery-1.7.2.js Line: 8240\"]"
```

I need to run this application locally and cannot put it on a webserver. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Mozilla documentation on same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs), your XML file must be inside a **subdirectory** of your page's source directory.

For example your site may be structured like this:

```
 my-site/
     index.html
     script.js
     data/
         branding.xml
```

This on the other hand will **NOT** work:

```
 my-site/
     source/
         index.html
         script.js
     data/
         branding.xml
```